# I have wine data with 177 rows and 14 columns . I need to drop 3, 5,8, 10, 12,13th colums

Tags: python

wine.drop(wine.columns[2,4,7,9,11,12], axis=1, inplace= True)

while performing this I am getting error

as too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 6 were indexed

Please help why its happening

Comment: You should wrap the indexes in a list: `wine.drop(wine.columns[[2,4,7,9,11,12]]...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use iloc to index columns by integer indexes:

```
df1.drop(df1.iloc[:, [2,4,7,9,11,12]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```